# can cognito attributes also be used in an assumed IAM role in another AWS account?

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

i am using the `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` placeholder in the authenticated role of a cognito/identity user pool to give the cognito users fine grained access to their resources. As described [for example here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html) this works great if the resources are in the same account as the IAM role.

Now i want to do the same thing but for resources in another account. How would i for example do the following?:

- "userX" from userpool in accountA can access logGroup with name "userX" in accountB

Comment: Did you had a chance to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

So apparently it works with s3Buckets for example but you need to also give the mentioned s3 bucket in AccountB a resource policy which allows all users from AccountA to access this bucket. For example with terraform (btw this is to make amplify's upload feature work with a bucket in a different AWS account from amplify project):

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "authenticated_role" {
  name               = "${local.identity_pool_name}-authenticated-user"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.authenticated_role_document.json
  tags               = var.tags
  inline_policy {
    name = "authenticated_role_policy"
    policy = jsonencode({
        Version = "2012-10-17"
        Statement = [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::${var.accountBBucket}/public/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::${var.accountBBucket}/protected/$${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::${var.accountBBucket}/private/$${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
...
    ]
    })
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "shared_customer_artefacts_pol" {
  provider = aws.accountB
  bucket   = aws_s3_bucket.shared_customer_artefacts.id
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid    = "1"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          AWS = "arn:aws:iam::${var.accountAId}:root"
        }
        Action = [
          "s3:ListBucket",
          "s3:GetObject",
          "s3:PutObject",
        ]
        Resource = [
          "arn:aws:s3:::${var.var.accountBBucket}",
          "arn:aws:s3:::${var.var.accountBBucket}/*",
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

Comment: Couple of questions: 
1. Were the cognito variables available in the IAM assumed role request?

Comment: 2. Does granting resource policy grants access to all objects to users in account A or is it to make everything work? 

I am trying to understand if this resource policy will allow a user to download any object from that S3 bucket?